# How to properly Bind data from MongoDB in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I'm using two components to get data from the DB. One that I'm using to loop through them and a second one to access and view the data for each entry. I have a field in DB called 'sex' in which the users submits either male, female and/or other. I'm trying to do an if statement but it is not working or maybe I'm not that good as I though.

I have done this in the file(Secrets.js) in which I'm looping through(I'm using a different component within as well) them:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import SecretItem from './SecretItem';
import { getSecrets } from '../../actions/secret';

const Secrets = ({ getSecrets, secret: { secrets, loading } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getSecrets();
  }, [getSecrets]);
  return loading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <Fragment>
          {secrets.map(secret => (
            <SecretItem key={secret._id} secret={secret} />
          ))}
        </Fragment>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Secrets.propTypes = {
  getSecrets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  secret: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  secret: state.secret
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getSecrets }
)(Secrets);
```

The problem it is not that I'm not able to fetch data because I actually can, I can get the title, date, text, etc. What the real problem is - is when wanting to fetch conditional data as said in the first paragraph. Here it is my SecretItem component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteSecret } from '../../actions/secret';

const SecretItem = ({ secret: { _id, age, sex, text, date } }) => {
  if (sex === 'male') {
    const sexo = 'male';
  } else if (sex === 'female') {
    const sexo = 'female';
  } else {
    const sexo = 'other';
  }
  return (
    <article className={`card text-center ${_id}`}>
      <div className="card-header">
        <span className="badge age badge-info">{age}</span>
        <span className="badge sex badge-secondary">{sexo}</span>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <P>{date}</P>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

SecretItem.propTypes = {
  secret: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteSecret: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { deleteSecret }
)(SecretItem);
```

So far it just keeps throwing me error of undefined or it simply do not display anything. Allow me to say this is my first time using React, I actually never had troubles with JavaScript so if any of you guys can guide and me and tell me what my error is, please do so.

Comment: FYI `sexo` is not in scope because you're assigning to it inside a block in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Li357 said your scope of `sexo` was unreachable.

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteSecret } from '../../actions/secret';

const SecretItem = ({ secret: { _id, age, sex, text, date } }) => {
  const sexo = sex || 'other';

  return (
    <article className={`card text-center ${_id}`}>
      <div className="card-header">
        <span className="badge age badge-info">{age}</span>
        <span className="badge sex badge-secondary">{sexo}</span>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <P>{date}</P>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

SecretItem.propTypes = {
  secret: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteSecret: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { deleteSecret }
)(SecretItem);
```

If the value of sexo becomes more complex to set, you have to define the value as a let instead, before the conditional statements. For example:

```js
let sexo = 'not specified' 

if (sex === 'male') {
  sexo = 'male';
} else if (sex === 'female') {
  sexo = 'female';
} else {
  sexo = 'other';
}
```